# Resizing a background image in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and I currently have the following code stored in a *.css* file. What is the best way to allow for auto resize if the user changes the window size? I tried to use the following code to allow for this but I was not able to get the intended result.

```
body {
    background-image: url('Images/Space.jpg');
    text-align: center;
}

text {
    color:white;    
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you also added your HTML code or create a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width 100%` makes responsive, image cover does the same, but more usefull no need to set width or height

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  
body { 
 background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_flowers.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CSS background-size Property`.

```
body {
    background-image: url('Images/Space.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```